# Error in JSON result for one to many mapping in Spring-Data-Jpa

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Owner Entity: PriceListItemTest.java

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"pricingUOMCode","lineTypeCode","primaryPricingUOMFlag","priceListId","itemId","priceListItemId"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS")
public class PriceListItemTest implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "price_list_item_id")    
    private String priceListItemId;

    @Column(name = "pricing_uom_code")  
    private String pricingUOMCode; 

    @Column(name = "line_type_code")    
    private String lineTypeCode; 

    @Column(name = "primary_pricing_uom_flag")  
    private String primaryPricingUOMFlag;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")   
    private String itemId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priceListItemsTest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ItemDetailTest> itemDetailsTest;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and Entity2 : ItemDetailTest.java

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"itemNumber","inventoryItemId","organizationId"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "egp_system_items_b")
public class ItemDetailTest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "inventory_item_id") 
    private String inventoryItemId; 

    @Column(name = "item_number")   
    private String itemNumber; 

    @Column(name = "organization_id")   
    private String organizationId;


//   To be used for bidirectional   
    @ManyToOne//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PriceListItemTest priceListItemsTest;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The RestController is returning error while retrieving the JSON result.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-23T14:05:26.248+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListItemTest[\"itemDetailsTest\"])",
    "path": "/getByItemIdTest"
}
```

May be the mapping oneTomany is wrong.
It is working fine if it has oneToone mapping but facing problem with OneToMany.
Can someone please help me with the error?

Edit:
Controller:

```
@RestController
public class PriceListItemControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private PriceListItemRepositoryTest priceListItemRepositoryTest;

    @GetMapping(value="/getByItemIdTest")
    public List<PriceListItemTest> getByItemIdTest(@RequestParam("itemId") String itemId) {
        return priceListItemRepositoryTest.findByItemId(itemId);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can post you rest controller and API request and logs it will be more helpful for us.

Comment: I have added the Rest Controller

Answer (score 6):

Change your model class like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS")
public class PriceListItemTest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -748956247024967638L;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price_list_item_id")    
    private String priceListItemId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "pricing_uom_code")  
    private String pricingUOMCode; 

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "line_type_code")    
    private String lineTypeCode; 

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "primary_pricing_uom_flag")  
    private String primaryPricingUOMFlag;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id")   
    private String itemId;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priceListItemsTest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ItemDetailTest> itemDetailsTest;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "egp_system_items_b")
public class ItemDetailTest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8495817802073010928L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "inventory_item_id") 
    private String inventoryItemId; 

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "item_number")   
    private String itemNumber; 

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "organization_id")   
    private String organizationId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_item_id", nullable = false) // name of the foreign key column
    private PriceListItemTest priceListItemsTest;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In your JoinColumn provide the actual name of the foreign key field. It should work as Jackson will automatically serialize.

For One To many refernces you can follow these links: [link1](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/) and [link2](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/)

Answer (score 5):

use @JsonIgnore like in the below. problem is infinite json calls are going through your json call. to ignore that use this annotation on your ManytoOne relation. worked fine for me.

```
@ManyToOne//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private PriceListItemTest priceListItemsTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a bidirectional mapping between the two entities and this would cause an infinit loop during JSON serialization.

You must ignore one of the sides using @JsonIgnore for example.

Read more about that topic here:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion